# registerForActivityResult TakePicture not triggered

Tags: android, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

I trying to new registerForActivityResult for taking picture. I can open Camera Intent, but after taking picture, callback is not triggered and i can't see anything about Activity Result or an error on logcat.

I tried also RequestPermission, it's triggered. I couldn't find, what's wrong.

My code is here:

```
class UploadDocumentFragment {

    private val registerTakePicture = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()
    ) { isSuccess ->
        if (isSuccess) {
            viewModel.addDocToRequest()
            viewModel.setSelectedDocument(null)
        } else {
            R.string.internal_error.showAsDialog { }
        }
    }

    //...

    private fun takeImage() {
        val photoFile: File? = viewModel.createImageFile()
        photoFile?.also {
            val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                requireContext(),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".fileProvider",
                it
            )
            registerTakePicture.launch(photoURI)
        }
    }
}
```

createImageFile function on ViewModel:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun createImageFile(): File? {
    val imageFileName = selectedDocumentTypeLD.value?.visibleName
    return try {
        val file = File(storageDir, "$imageFileName.jpg")
        if (file.createNewFile() || file.exists()) {
            file
        } else {
            null
        }
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```

App gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha06'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha06'
```

Comment: Thank you for the question. Today, by completer happenstance I found out that this framework exists! And the Google guide was a little short on specifics of the App gradle.

Comment: Could you show what your VM's `createImageFile()` method does?

Comment: @Sampson I added to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I found the problem.

My previous onActivityResult function was still there. I thought maybe the old function could override registerForActivityResult. When I remove the old function, registerForActivityResult works very well.

Comment: This situation can also occur if you initialize a variable `registerTakePicture` in the onStart method.
I lost two days until I understand that.

Comment: I dont have "onActivityResult" method, it still not triggered. When I implement onActivityResult in parent activity, it is triggered there.

Comment: i found that when using this method, the onCleared of my view model gets called. do you know how to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, problem was `android:noHistory="true"` in manifest in the container activity (activity that contains all fragments).

Removing this called `registerForActivityResult()` in fragment.