# StartActivityForResult to get images from gallery in MVVM architecture?

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I am using MVVM architecture for my `PhotoEditorActivity`, the activity plays the View role. When user clicks "Pick Image" button, I want to start gallery to pick an image and get back its uri to update an ImageView. I am confused in where to call `startActivityForResult()`.

- Call `startActivityForResult()` from View: By this way, the activity processes everything, ViewModel and Model become redundant.
- Call `startActivityForResult()` from ViewModel and View observes Uri from the ViewModel: I can pass `Context` to ViewModel to start activity, but I can not receive uri because ViewModel does not have `onActivityResult()`.
- Call `startActivityForResult()` from Model: View pass a `Context` to ViewModel, ViewModel continue passing the `Context` to Model. Using this way, I face the same issue with the second way.

Could you please help me how to properly apply MVVM for this business. What should each component contain? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

All Android related things are best handled in the View. Specifically making your code loosely coupled depends on what you intended to do with the image / file that you have selected.
If for example you are trying to upload it as a bitmap, then you should create the bitmap in the view and pass it to the view model.
Also, onActivityResult is now depreciated. See the [official documentation for it here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).
You may also want to look at [this answer for an example implementation of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497463/registerforactivityresult-takepicture-not-triggered#comment111000417_62497463).

Comment: Thank for your answer, It means that I should startActivity in View and don't mind to ViewModel and Model in this task, right?

Comment: Yes. As an example, when I want to get location, I do that in the main activity, and when the location is generated I pass it on the view model, and from there it goes into my repository. If you found the answer helpful, please up vote it.

Comment: Thank you, Your answer is helpful for me, i have upvoted

Comment: @TaQuangTu Did you find the solution? I am also stuck on this please help.